# Properly store while loop result in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I have three vectors:

```
N <- c(213,214,215,216)
R <- c(0.11937253,0.11937253, 0.11937253,0.11937253)
P <- c(0.549252447, 0.549252447, 0.549252447, 0.549252447)
```

from this vectors I am trying to get a result using a customized function with a nested while loop:

```
tmp <- function(N,R,P) {
err <- c()
i = 2
while ((N[i-1]+R[i-1]+P[i-1]) < 220) {
if (is.na(N[i])) {
break {
} else {
err <- N[i]/(R[i]+P[i])
i = i + 1
print(err)
  }
}
```

The focus is on storing `err`. Using `print` I can properly see my results (which should be a vector), but when I use `return` R gives me only the first element of the iteration. How can I get the proper output? It should be a vector containing all the elements coming from the iteration.

NB. Don’t focus on the condition, it’s just a proxy, the real one is another but I checked it and there is no problem there. Moreover, I built an if statement since the the condition of the while loop is very rare and can be it never happens and it would iterate for ever.

Comment: You need `err <- c(err, N[i]/(R[i]+P[I]))` instead.  Essentially, you need to keep all the previous results and add another.  Your building `err` element by element.

Comment: Should I place it before the last 2 curly brackets?

Comment: No, you should place it in the `else` part, instead of `err <- N[i]/(R[i]+P[i])`, and then `return(err)` before the last bracket. The reason is that `err <- N[i]/(R[i]+P[I])` in your initial code just erases the previous value of err instead of adding a new value.

Answer (score 1):

The `print()` function sends a result to the console, but doesn't save it in any other way.  You need a combination of what was suggested in the comments.  You need to keep adding to `err` each iteration and then return it at the end of the function.

```r
N <- c(213,214,215,216)
R <- c(0.11937253,0.11937253, 0.11937253,0.11937253)
P <- c(0.549252447, 0.549252447, 0.549252447, 0.549252447)


tmp <- function(N,R,P) {
  err <- c()
  i = 2
  while ((N[i-1]+R[i-1]+P[i-1]) < 220) {
    if (is.na(N[i])) {
      break 
      } else {
        e <- N[i]/(R[i]+P[i])
        err <- c(err, e)
        i = i + 1
        print(e)
        }
  }
  return(err)
}

out <- tmp(N, R, P)
#> [1] 320.0598
#> [1] 321.5554
#> [1] 323.051

out
#> [1] 320.0598 321.5554 323.0510
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp <- function(N, R, P) {
  s <- N + R + P
  i <- which(s < 220)
  (N[i] / (R[i] + P[i]))[-1]
}

tmp(N, R, P)

# [1] 320.06 321.56 323.05
```